# Unwrapping two optionals from Text Field

Tags: swift

I'm writing a simply app that includes calculating an area from user input of ID and OD in text fields. The label for the area is hidden until both ID and OD are entered. I'm having trouble unwrapping the optionals of ID and OD text field, to avoid error if user presses "return" without putting any number. This is what I wrote, which I thought would not run the area calculation codes unless both fields contain numbers (I've restricted keyboard to numbers only), but when I press "return" in either field without entering anything, I'm still getting the "nil optional error" in the area calculation code.

```swift
//move onto next field after return
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else{
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }        
        //calculate and display gasket area
        if textField == self.gasketODInput || textField == self.gasketIDInput {
            if let gasketIDString = gasketIDInput?.text, let gasketODString = gasketODInput?.text{
                    gasketArea = 0.7854*(Float(gasketODString)!*Float(gasketODString)!-Float(gasketIDString)!*Float(gasketIDString)!)
                    gasketAreaLabel.text = String(gasketArea)
                    self.gasketAreaLabel.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Restricting the keyboard to numbers only does not guarantee you will only get numbers. Users may copy and paste or use a bluetooth keyboard for example. You therefore should not (actually never) force unwrap the Float constructor.

Comment: Noted. I've changed it to rmaddy's recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to safely unwrap the attempts to convert the text to `Float`.

```
if let gasketIDString = gasketIDInput?.text,
   let gasketODString = gasketODInput?.text,
   let gasketOD = Float(gasketODString),
   let gasketID = Float(gasketIDString) {

    gasketArea = 0.7854 * (gasketOD * gasketOD - gasketID * gasketID)
    gasketAreaLabel.text = String(gasketArea)
    self.gasketAreaLabel.isHidden = false
}
```